# Namespace Reference Bug (or me being an idiot)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution that contains to class library projects named "CompanyName.Data" and "ComanyName.Utilities".

If I create another class library project and reference the two projects, everything works fine. If, however, I choose a web app then, despite adding the reference, the other namespaces cannot be referenced in the project.

It's as if I haven't imported the namespace or done the reference at all.

FYI, I'm running VS2012. Any advice? Am I missing something obvious? I'm going to do some more experimenting.

Regards,
Chris.

**UPDATE: The issue seems to not be a web app but be when the web app project is named "Company.Something".**

Comment: Did you check if the target framework versions are same?

Comment: They are the same. .net 4.5

Comment: Can you check what error VS gives.. in the output window?

Comment: May be you use .net framework client profile in 2 dll?

Comment: Nope ... not the Client Profile ... its a web app

Comment: What **exactly** does the IDE / compiler say?

Comment: what is the namespace of your web app, and did you import the namespaces using the `using` directive in addition to adding the reference to the dll?

Comment: "The type or namespace '<namespace name>' does not exist in the class or namespace '<parent namespace>' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Ok, what about #2 - did you import the namespace using the `using` directive?

Comment: I did add the reference and provide a using the namespace (as intellisence didn't pick it up)

Comment: Creating an web app NOT "Company.Something" works ... it only seems to be broken if the web app name is "Company.Something"

Comment: interesting problem you have, now **I am** interested to find out what the problem is, is it vs, or are you actually a clown trying to entertain us?   :P

Comment: @Jason ... lol ... I've tweeted Scott Hanselman ... I think it's a VS "feature" but don't understand why. At the moment, the workaround is changing the project name but I don't want to.

Comment: haha, good luck, make sure you update once you figure it out, i don't have vs2012 right now (on this pc), but would like to know what's going on there, seems pretty crazy  :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who reads this and thinks the same. This 'feature' is by design. It's a safety measure to prevent clashing against the plethora of namespaces created in a web application. I don't quite understand myself, but that's the official word.